# css float browser size

Tags: html, css, css-float

I am new to css/html and I am trying to create a simple website.
I want to ask what to do if I want to use float(left or right) but I don't want the objects to move when I adjust the size of the browser's tab?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. put the site in a container (fixed width element)
2. use percentages and em based element widths to respond to browser window size at a proportion.

First ex

```
<div id=container style="width: 960px">
  <!-- child elemetns here --> 
</div>
```

Comment: if you are trying to create a responsive site then you would go with option #2.